# How to turn off the Ubuntu initialization sound?

Tags: ubuntu

The System->Preferences->Sound have no option for that..

(using ubuntu 9.10)

**--update for @JonT**

Mycustom.config file:

> [daemon]
>
> [security]
>
> [xdmcp]
>
> [gui]
>
> [greeter]
>
> SoundOnLogin=false
>
> [chooser]
>
> [debug]
>
> [servers]

Comment: The what sound?

Comment: @Ignacio the sound made when you login

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to System->Preferences->Startup Applications. Uncheck `GNOME Login Sound`. That'll disable the sound you get when you log in.

Comment: Unmark it didn't worked (as I logout and login it get back marked). But remove it worked, thanks! =)

Answer (score 2):

Its in: `System->Administration->Login Screen->Check box(Play login sound)`

Comment: did you find it?

Comment: hi, there's no such checkbox here..

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to the sound on the login screen, open up the file `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` and under the `[greeter]` section, insert this:

```
SoundOnLogin=false
```

you will probably need to open the above file with sudo, so use `sudo gedit /etc/gdm/custom.conf` or it will not allow you to save.

You can turn off all Ubuntu event sounds with gconftool:

```
gksudo -u gdm gconftool-2 –set /desktop/gnome/sound/event_sounds –type bool false
```

Comment: I believe instead of `sudo gedit /etc/gdm/custom.conf` it is more Linuxxy to use `gksu gedit /etc/gdm/custom.conf` (as `sudo` is for console commands, while gksu/gksudo/kdesu are for X/graphical applications).

Comment: @chr You will see the same result as long as you've entered the sudo password within the grace period.

Comment: @John - I thought it was considered bad to use sudo for graphical applicattions - something to do with creating files that are owned by root and cause problems later???

Comment: @Andy can you point me to the source of where you got this information? Because it's entirely wrong. gksudo will present you with a graphical dialog asking you for your password as opposed to sudo which asks you for it on the command line. It doesn't create any files.

Comment: @John I agree with you, but also found there are certain cases where this is a problem (http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/graphicalsudo). I use `sudoedit filename` in any case.

Comment: @John - Little bit confrontational with your style there... I did use three question marks, which I think is sufficient to indicate it's not certain and based on hard evidence! I didn't mean to imply that sudo itself created files: KeyboardMonkey's link explains exactly the sort of problem I was thinking of - _Change a few settings while launched as root, and you'll see if you dig into your Firefox profile that certain files are now owned by root._

Comment: @john: here you'll find what the Ubuntu Documentation says about using sudo for graphical applications. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo EDIT: for the lazy..."gksudo sets HOME=~root, and copies .Xauthority to a tmp directory. This prevents files in your home directory becoming owned by root."

Comment: @dag you are correct, but this does not hinder people's ability to **launch** the applications in any way. It simply states what can happen while you are using a program that **was launched** with the sudo utility. Thanks for doing some research on it though :) I will update the answer if it means **this much** to people O_o

Comment: @john: it was just for the sake of completeness! :D

Comment: Hi! I just tested it, logged out and in, and still hear the little login-music... It didn't worked.. :(

Comment: By the way, I would prefer to turn off just the login sound..

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) for that. It's easy to install and you can disable the start-up sound with a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Can't remember exactly, but I think it's in "Login Screen" and/or "Appearance" section.